# Visual Studio 2010 Javascript comments stopped working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, xml-comments

When I type /// visual studio no longer adds xml comments in to my javascript document. I've installed a number of extensions recently and wondered if these may have caused it, one of which recently expired (re-sharper). I've tried disabling and running visual studio in safe mode (Devenv.exe /SafeMode) and reset my settings (devenv.exe /ResetSettings). I know it was working previously as I have comments in documents

Comment: I found another way to insert them using cnt+k, followed by cnt+x from the site below. I'd still like to know how to re-enable the /// functionality though. http://www.netsi.dk/wordpress/index.php/2010/09/22/improvements-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2010-from-a-frontend-webdevelopers-point-of-view-part-1-javascript/

Comment: It was re-sharper that was providing the functionality. I've been told that this functionality will be added to VS11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is functionality that ReSharper provides, but you can add snippets in Visual Studio using `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+X` and use the [Snippet Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb973770) to populate the `summary`, `param` and `returns` elements.

This article also details [How to Create JScript XML Code Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx).