# VS2010 JavaScript XML documentation

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, comments

Is there any way to get Visual Studio to automatically add the XML comment blocks for functions/methods like it does for C# when you type ///? If not, is there any (preferably free) extension that will do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please look at a similar question here [Visual Studio 2010 Javascript comments stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519037/visual-studio-2010-javascript-comments-stopped-working)

Basically, the best thing to do is to get resharper. Click the link to learn about a workaround without resharper.

Comment: Mods: Sorry but I don't have commenting ability so far.

Comment: I did and Resharper seems like overkill for what I want really.

Comment: You could give the `Ctrl + K` followed by `Ctrl + X` to insert a snippet as another option. :)